# Controlling emission of Observable items in unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java

I have a class that subscribes to a dependency-provided observable and stores the resulting subscription, so that it can be cancelled if a new request comes in.

```
public class A {
    private final Client client;

    private Subscription subscription;

    public void doSomething() {
        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }

        subscription = client.request().subscribe(/* log event */);
    }
}
```

How can I test this unsubscribing behavior without exposing `subscription`?

I'm thinking of simulating this flow:

- `doSomething()` called once. Mock `client` returns observable O1 that does not emit anything yet. Verify that `/* log event */` didn't happen.
- `doSomething()` called again. Mock `client` returns observable O2 that emits immediately. Verify that `/* log event */` happened.
- Have O1 emit an item, verify `/* log event */` didn't happen again.

If that's a recommended approach, I don't know how to have O1 emit items at specific steps of my test.

Otherwise, is there any kind of `TestObservable` like there is a `TestSubscriber`, which would help verify the number of subscriptions at any time?

Comment: I recommend storing the Subscriber not the returned Subscription because when processing synchronously the Subscription is not returned till finished!  The Subscriber also has a .unsubscribe() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit more experience in this domain, today I would have the dependency return a `Subject`, and assert that this subject only has one observer after calling `doSomething()` twice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`TestScheduler`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/TestScheduler.html) to time things:

> The TestScheduler is useful for debugging. It allows you to test schedules of events by manually advancing the clock at whatever pace you choose.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use a test scheduler to emit arbitrary items? I've managed to use it with `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` but it would emit `Long` and I need, say, `Response`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `observable.doOnSubscribe(action)` and `doOnUnsubscribe(action)` to monitor subscription events.